# NSForwarding: warning: selector. This error only occured when my mac has less free memory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, runtime-error

This error only occured when my mac has less free memory

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0xc2a9470) for message 'Ù,T`ï*' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime (0x1505b3c0)-- abort
2013-09-03 15:35:28.267 ********[8579:1e803] (null): unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3542cf4
```

And xcode showed me error code line:

```
inputViewScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 400)];
```

I closed some apps were running (firefox, mail, skype ...) and try to run again... and it's OK!

But when free memory is less, this error occurred again! What's happening?

I'm using Mac Mini, Mac OSX 10.7.5, ram 4gb, xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Had a similar thing happening to me today. After finding your post, I've checked my PC resources and noticed that my RAM was also a bit low. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that this was the reason, and that it only happens during development.